# Does flex have a long expected lifespan

Tags: html, flash, apache-flex

**EDIT JAN 2014 - No Longer relevant answer has been played out in the mean time.**

This is a cross post. I've already posted the question to flexcoders.

We work in flex as a technology. However a potential client has stated that they are worried about the lifespan of flex as a technology. Especially as apple doesn't support it on their mobile devices, and the increasing support for HTML5 within browsers.

What I would like is to be able to show them some figures about any large adopters. Especially in enterprise. Just to show that it isn't some flash in the pan technology. (No pun indended)

For those interested you can [view my original question](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/flexcoders/message/157045).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [many very large enterprises using Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/customers/list.html).  Check out some of the [testimonials](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/customers/saying.html) and the [Flex Showcase](http://flex.org/showcase).

Answer (score 3):

Does your client deal with video?  If so, then it is likely that over the course of the next 5-10 years the HTML5 video tag could replace Flash as the default video player on the web.  However, even if HTML5 chips away at Flash's relevance as a video player; why would that affect Flex's ability to provide a Smart Application GUI?

Does your client build games?  It is possible--although I believe unlikely--that the HTML5 Canvas element will be used for a lot of web games.  IF this aspect of HTML5 chips away at Flash's relevance as a web game platform, why would that affect Flex's ability to provide a smart Application GUI?

Additionally, why did your client choose Flex over an AJAX solution?  Would the same reason apply to an HTML5 choice?

It is also probable that Adobe will keep innovating The Flash Player and Flex faster than HTML5.  Flex has a mature toolset with lots of support.

I'd also ask why is it important for your client to provide applications support on mobile devices?  The answer to that question will have a big affect on the client's decision whether to use Flash or not.

I don't have any specific numbers or case studies to share, though.  [YouTube](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/06/flash-and-html5-tag.html) had a Blog post about why they chose Flash.  So did [Hulu](http://blog.hulu.com/2010/05/13/pardon-our-dust/).  Of course, I do not know if either of them are using Flex.

Comment: +1. Although I disagree on "The Flash Player and Flex faster than HTML5". Flex is actually quite resource hungry and slow. And a properly hardware accelerated renderer with a JS runtime as the V8 can possibily even outperform flash.

Comment: We chose flex. They are questioning our choice. The senario is more like a dashboard/system control. It only complements the public part of the website. They want to know the system is maintainable in the long haul.

Comment: back2dos, thanks for the +1; however I said that I expect Adobe to innovate the platform faster than HTML5 will innovate.  Innovation, or platform evolution, has nothing do with memory usage or runtime efficiency.  I expect we'll see multiple releases of the Flash Player, AIR, and Flex before anyone gives a thought to an HTML6.

Comment: Wes, I can't fathom why the system wouldn't be maintainable, can you!  A better question is Will Flex fill their business needs in the long haul?  That is something for you, and them, to answer based on an understanding of their biz and long term goals / strategies.

Comment: ME either. I don't really think they should push a technology on us as at the end of the day we have to build the system. I was looking for evidence that I could show them that its not a flash in the pan thing.

Comment: Is the Flash Player's 14 year history not considered evidence that Flash is not a "Flash in the pan" thing?  I'm not sure what evidence I could offer. On the last earnings call, Shantanu said the number of Flash Platform developers / designers is 3.5 million and those numbers grew 59% in 2009.  ( http://www.adobe.com/aboutadobe/invrelations/pdfs/q210script.pdf ).  That's huge growth although it's unknown to me where he came up with the 59% number.

Comment: Yes adobe can make rapid changes to flash anytime they want, html5 is a slow process and isn't even finished yet.

Answer (score 0):

This should be an large adopter: [SAP](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/sap/)